# Google Column Chart: Column height not in proportion to the value

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am using the Google Column Chart to visualize data.

**Problem:**

Unfortunately with a certain input the heights of the column bars are not in proportion.

---

**Error Reproduction:**

[I reconstructed this in a simple JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2betxw5u/).

[Here is an other example, which contains a working and a not working version.](https://jsfiddle.net/2betxw5u/1)

---

**Question:**

How can the issue be fixed, so that the height is proportional to the value differences of my columns.

If for example one column has the value 20.000 and an other 40.000, the height of the first one should be half as high as for the second column.

Thank you so much.

---

**Code examples & images:**

Here is my jsFiddleCode:

*Html:*

```
<body>
  <h1>
    Weird height of <a href="https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart">Google Column Chart</a> Bars.
  </h1>

  <div id="columnchart_values"></div>

    <h1>
    Correct height of <a href="https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart">Google Column Chart</a> Bars.
  </h1>

  <div id="columnchart_values2"></div>

</body>
```

*Javascript*:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  var parts = x.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");

  if( typeof( parts[1] ) != 'undefined' ){
    parts[1] = parts[1].substr(0,2);
  }

  return parts.join(",");
}

function drawChart1() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Quelle', 'Geldbetrag', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['test1', 40000, '#11368A', 'Cu' ],
    ['test2', 29400, '#000357', 'Ag' ],
    ['test3', 22193, '#40F020', 'Au' ],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
function drawChart2() {
/*only the data of test 3 changed*/
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Quelle', 'Geldbetrag', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['test1', 40000, '#11368A', 'Cu' ],
    ['test2', 29400, '#000357', 'Ag' ],
    ['test3', 19000, '#40F020', 'Au' ],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values2"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart'], 'language': 'de'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( function(){
    drawChart1();
  drawChart2();
} );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The current behavior is to remain backward compatible with the way it used to be years ago.  Now it will include the baseline value in the chart if it is "close enough" to the data.   But you can force the baseline value of the bars to be included in the chart by simply specifying the baseline value explicitly.  For your example, just add:

`vAxis: { baseline: 0 }`

to your options.  See https://jsfiddle.net/2betxw5u/2/

Answer (score 0):

Adding: vAxis: {minValue: 0, format: '€ #,###'} to the options solves the problem.